# define own time in linux

Tags: time

how to set time in linux in that way:

1 second define as 10 seconds
(10 second = 1 secods of own time)

I want fool all processes runned there to use 10x faster time.
so `sleep(1)` will last 0.1 real seconds.

how to achieve it?

Comment: what is the purpose ?

Comment: ... if purpose is unknown the question is not worth answearing ... ? I want special system environment.

Comment: @user1999710 It is often beneficial to state your ultimate goal in the question; it makes it possible to suggest alternative solutions which might be better suited to accomplishing your end goal. Otherwise, it can very easily become a [XY problem question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157730). Also consider [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask); particularly, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." While not always necessary for that, again stating the end goal often helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run a command (including a shell and all of its children) with an arbitrary faster clock frequency by using the `warp` command from the [ast-open](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Eastopen/download/gen/ast-open.html) package. It uses LD_PRELOAD, so won't work with setuid or setgid or (now relatively rare) statically-linked programs. From the [warp man page](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Eastopen/man/man1/warp.html):

> warp [ options ] date [ command [ arg ... ] ]
>
> **warp** executes a dynamically linked command in a different time frame by intercepting time related system calls and modifying the times seen by *command* using the formula:
>
> time' = time + warp + (time - base) * (factor - 1)
>
> where *warp* is date-now, *base* is date by default, and *factor* is 1 by default.
>
> OPTIONS
>
> -b, --base=date
>
> > Set the base or starting date to *date*. Useful for repeating a set of tests. The default value is date.
>
> -f, --factor=factor
>
> > Set the warped clock to tick at *factor* seconds per real second. The default value is 1.
>
> **warp** executes *command* with optional args, or **sh** if *command* is omitted. All processes executed by *command* are warped in the same time frame. Time progresses for *command* and its children at the rate of *factor* times the system clock. Any files created by *command* or its children will appear newer than *date* to *command* and its children, but will actually be in the normal time frame for non-warped commands.