# Is it possible to speed up my Linux Clock?

Tags: linux, clock

Is it possible to modify the Unix Time Clock so that the clock is running ten times faster? Something like a fast-forward by increasing a clock frequency or change the  clock tick time?

Background is that i'am waiting here for an application that running on a linux system which has huge timeouts (hourly). I want to bypass these long timeouts with a faked clock. Which side effects can occur here?

Comment: Related: [define own time in Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136954/define-own-time-in-linux)

Comment: Do you need the entire system to run fast, or would it be sufficient to restart this one application and have just it run faster?

Answer (score 4):

You might try writing your own gettimeofday() routine, loading it into a compiled library, and using LD_PRELOAD to have your application get a faked time. This should not affect any other applications.

Comment: The LD_PRELOAD trick is described  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick