# Run Debian System Faster then real time

Tags: linux

Is there a, preferably simple, way to run a Linux system faster than real time.

For example have it go through a month in a day.

The use case is that I am setting up some logging, cron and backup utilities and I would like to be able to test a few things that are only are supposed to run every few days or so.

Comment: Would it be possible to decrease the time period between cronjobs for the test? The test server could instead execute the tasks every few seconds/minutes/hours instead of days/weeks/months. Obviously you would need to give enough of a gap between tasks so a backup job or other type of transaction could be completed before the next one starts.

Comment: You might like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85336/117549

Comment: This is an amazing x-y question. I would love to know how to get a system to run like this though! Also, check this question out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136954/define-own-time-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

Write a script, that sets the system clock to one second in the future, 30 times per second ;-)